# Is there an easier way to create this vector that doesn't require loops?

Tags: r, loops, optimization

I'm trying to make a single vector that pairs up values. For example if the 2nd element is 100, I want the 100th element to be 2. In a sense, each element of the vector has its own respective pair.

I'm using this vector in a function later.

I've currently tried working with the mapply and for loop in similar ways, but these take too long and I keep thinking that there must be a more optimal way for doing this. Perhaps a variation of the sample function?

I want a 'paired' vector of length 10^5

```
set.seed(1)

tmp <- 1:10^5
t1 <- c(sample(1:10^5, 5))
t2 <- tmp[-t1]
t2 <- sample(t2)

for (i in 1:10^5) {
  if (tmp[i] %in% t1) {
    a <- which(t1 == tmp[i])
    tmp[i] <- t2[a]
  } else {
    a <- which(t2 ==tmp[i])
    tmp[i] <- t1[a]
  }
}
```

Basically it all works, it's just that it takes way too long. I'm sure there must be a more optimal way of doing this.

I need the pairings to be random, so doing them for the fist 50 000 and then the other 50 000 wouldn't work.

Comment: the objects `v1` and `a` are not vectors but numerics of length one. I don't understand what your desired output is? 
Maybe post a smaller example with only 10 components instead of 10^5.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I am a bit confused about what you are trying to accomplish. It seems you set v1 and then never do anything with it. Could you try to add some more language about the operation (and maybe a complete smaller example?)

Comment: Sorry! I managed I accidentally copy down a mix of the code I used in the mapply version of this in the for loop, which obviously then didn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe if I have understood you correctly you can do

```
tmp <- 1:100
t1 <- sample(1:100, 50)
t2 <- tmp[-t1]
t2 <- sample(t2)


v2 <- integer(100)
v2[t1] <- t2
v2[t2] <- t1
```

This when compared with your `for` loop gives same result

```
for(i in 1:100) {
  if(tmp[i] %in% t1) {
    a <- which(t1 == tmp[i])
    v1[i] <- t2[a]
   }  else {
     a <- which(t2 ==tmp[i])
     v1[i] <- t1[a]
   }
}

identical(v1, v2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted and takes so much less time! Thank you!